# Make textsc insensitive to environment

Tags: theorems, small-caps, renewcommand

I'm using `textsc` inside an equation that then appears in a Theorem environment. I want the text in `textsc` inside the equation to appear in regular font, not italics (which is enforced by the Theorem environment).

That is, I want to avoid the difference noticed here (CLIQUE should render inside the theorem in the same style as in the first line).

```
We have the following result for $\textsc{Clique}$.
\begin{proposition}
$\textsc{Clique}$ is $\NP$-complete.
\end{proposition}
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this? Ideally, could this be done via renaming the `textsc` command? (since there are more complicated macros that use it and should also change their appearance in this way)

Comment: you shouldn't use a text command inside math. If it is a math variable, setup a mathfont e.g. \mathsc{Clique} or a special command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have several problems which you want to analyze with respect to NP-completeness, so it's best to define a specific command. The big advantage is that you can decide about the typographic realization even at the very last moment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newcommand{\NP}{\mathbf{NP}}
\newcommand{\prb}[1]{\textnormal{\scshape #1}}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

We have the following result for \prb{Clique}.

\begin{proposition}
\prb{Clique} is $\NP$-complete.
\end{proposition}

Also in math mode: $\prb{Clique}^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]